# How can I convert a file with the command line?

Tags: command-line, conversion

I want to convert a file from VRML to FBX without rendering the model using blender. Is this possible via command line?

edit:
I'm working on windows and tried the following:
I added the blender directory to my path environment variable. After that I wrote a .bat script with the following content:

```
start "" blender test.vrml --background --C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.76\scripts\addons\io_scene_x3d\import_x3d.py -- foobar.blend
start "" blender foobar.blend --background --C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.76\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx.py test.fbx
```

Unfortunately this opens a lot of windows until my windows crashes. I think the error is my lack of knowledge about .bat scripts :-(.

Answer (score 3):

According to the wiki, it is possible to [convert](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Wavefront_OBJ#Command_Line_Converting) (link is just an example, not specific to the formats you mentioned) via the command line. However, I'm not so certain (seeing as I haven't tested this) if you can convert between non-native formats.

I believe you would need to use the script to import VRML, then subsequently the script to export FBX.

If you are looking to automate the process, you could write a script that runs these commands sequentially:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec blender foobar.vrml --background --python name_of_import_plugin.py -- foobar.blend
exec blender foobar.blend --background --python name_of_fbx_export_plugin.py foobar.fbx
```

Please note you'd need to edit the above code, and I have not tested this, but in theory it should work.