# convert OBJ file to GLTF with only CLI

Tags: file-format, gltf, obj, conversion, terminology

is there a simple **TERMINAL ONLY** way to convert an .obj file .gltf file using blender,

---

with blender GUI i can do it like,

> file > import > .obj > [~/path/to/input.obj] > import .obj
>
>
> then:
>
> file > export > .gltf > [~/path/to/output.gltf] > import .gltf

---

maybe for ex:-

```bash
blender -i ~/path/to/input.obj -e ~/path/to/output.gltf
```

*like [-i for import & -e for export]*

---

is there a way to do this using a bash terminal, like `ffmpeg` or `convert [ImageMagick]` do file format conversion

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192420/how-to-import-obj-and-convert-and-export-as-fbx-from-command-line-in-python https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56009/how-can-i-convert-a-file-with-the-command-line

Comment: UX3D offers a conversion script, calling Blender in headless mode from the command line: https://github.com/ux3d/2gltf2